# Custom spray.io directive to validate request header value

Tags: scala, spray

I am new to spray and I am trying to write a custom directive. I would like the directive to reject the request if the header value is not valid otherwise leave the request alone.

I've tried to absorb this page:
http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/

Specifically, the part about the responder chain. I'm trying to create something at the level of the bar Directive in the illustration. I'm just not getting how to pass the context unchanged to the inner route.

My else block below is not correct but expresses what I am trying to do. I just can't figure out how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
trait ApiKeyDirective {
    import spray.routing.directives.HeaderDirectives._
    import spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives._

    def validateApiKey(): Directive1 = {

       headerValueByName("api-key") {key =>
           val valid = key == "123"
           if (!valid) reject() else pass
       }
    }
}

object ApiKeyDirective extends ApiKeyDirective
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just not getting how to pass the context unchanged to the inner
>   route.

Spray does that for you!

Your code is mostly correct, there are just 2 simple problems to fix!
Firstly, you need to `flatMap` `headerValueByName("api-key")` directive.
Secondly, the return type will be `Directive0` because the directive won't provide any value.

So final code would look like this:

```
object ApiKeyDirective {
  import spray.routing.Directives._

  val validateApiKey: Directive0 =
    headerValueByName("api-key").flatMap { key =>
      val valid = key == "123"
      if (!valid) reject() else pass
    }

}
```

Also, I recommend you to add a custom rejection to `reject()` block so that API users will be informed when their api key is invalid.

Comment: Thanks! I intend to reject with an AuthorizationFailedRejection but left it out for conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine

[`headerValueByName`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/header-directives/headerValueByName/):

```
def headerValueByName(headerName: String): Directive1[String]
```

with [`validate`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-routing/misc-directives/validate/):

```
def validate(check: ⇒ Boolean, errorMsg: String): Directive0
```

For example:

```
  def validateApiKey(route: Route) =
    headerValueByName("api-key") { key =>
      validate(key == "123", "Invalid API key") {
        route
      }
    }
```

or without `validate`:

```
  def validateApiKey(route: Route) =
    headerValueByName("api-key") { key =>
      if (key == "123")
        route
      else
        reject(ValidationRejection("Invalid API key"))
    }
```

Usage:

```
lazy val route = ...
    ... ~
    pathPrefix("test_directive") {
      get {
        validateApiKey {
          complete("ok")
        }
      }
    } ~
    ...
```

Test from cmd/shell:

```
# curl http://localhost:8080/test_directive
Request is missing required HTTP header 'api-key'

# curl http://localhost:8080/test_directive -H 'api-key: bad'
Invalid API key

# curl http://localhost:8080/test_directive -H 'api-key: 123'
"ok"
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really helpful to see possible variations.